# Outer join in decode in sql condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I was fetching a column latest control number from a table table_a. If there is no row for an employee in this table then it should return null. for this i created a query

**table_a**

```
control_num emp_num  approv_begin_date approv_end_date prov_end_date prov_begin_date
1           10        30-NOV-2014       30-JAN-2014     30-NOV-2014       30-JAN-2014
```

**table_b**

```
EMP_NUM  NAM
10       XYZ
20       ABC
```

I created a query :-

```
select nam,control_num
from table_a a,table_b b
where sysdate between approv_begin_date(+) and approv_end_date(+)
```

This is giving me the correct output which is

```
nam control_num
10  1
20
```

now the condition changed and i also have to consider the prov_end_date just in case the approve dates is null....
for this i created the following  condition

```
   select nam,control_num
    from table_a a,table_b b
    where sysdate between DECODE (approv_begin_date
,                NULL, a.prov_begin_date
,                a.approv_begin_date)and DECODE (approv_end_date
,                NULL, a.prov_end_date
,                a.approv_end_date)

this will just give me :
  nam control_num
    10  1
```

how do i use outer join here ?

Answer (score 3):

This is building on Thursday's answer.  I think the query is clearer as:

```
select nam, control_num
from table_b b left join
     table_a a
     on b.emp_num = a.emp_num and
        sysdate between coalesce(a.approv_begin_date, a.prov_begin_date) and
                        coalesce(a.approv_end_date, a.prov_end_date);
```

You should definitely learn explicit `join` syntax since it allows joins that the old style syntax doesn't.  In addition, `decode()` is specific to Oracle (is it deprecated yet?).  The ANSI standard method is `CASE`; however, for your purpose, `COALESCE()` is the right function and easy to use.

Note that `sysdate` has a time component.  It is quite likely that you really want:

```
trunc(sysdate) between coalesce(a.approv_begin_date, a.prov_begin_date) and
                             coalesce(a.approv_end_date, a.prov_end_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you change the join to something like this?

```
select nam,control_num
from table_a a
left join table_b b
  on b.emp_num = a.emp_num
where sysdate between DECODE (approv_begin_date
,                NULL, a.prov_begin_date
,                a.approv_begin_date)and DECODE (approv_end_date
,                NULL, a.prov_end_date
,                a.approv_end_date)
```